# Creating a JAR File from the Command Line Doesn't Work

Tags: java, class, jar, extract, pack

I've edited this question, and now it is exactly what I did:

I want to create a .jar file from some  .class files in the command line.

I worked on Eclipse, and created:

myProject project, and in it: myPackage package, and in it: myClass class.
Then I wrote in the command line:

```
jar -cfv myJar.jar  myPackage\myClass.class
```

And I got this:

```
added manifest
adding: myPackage/myClass.class(in = 745) (out= 473)(deflated 36%)
```

This really created the myJar.jar file in my current directory. Now, I wanted to check if the process was done successfully, so I extracted the class from the jar thus:

```
jar xfv myJar.jar
```

And I got this:

```
  created: META-INF/
 inflated: META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
 inflated: myPackage/myClass.class
```

And this created for me just the META-INF folder, with the MANIFEST.MF in it, but I don't see any .class file here!!

It seems like something in the packing to jar process is incorrect.

Anybody has an idea??

Any answer is appreciated!

Comment: What's the output of the command `ls` (or `dir` if on Windows), when executed in the same directory as the one you used to execute `jar -cf ...`?

Comment: Have you tried specifying `-v`?

Comment: Also, I think the command may be simply `cfv` without the `-` in front.

Comment: @JBNizet, this is the result:
'12/16/2012  05:30 PM    <DIR>          .

12/16/2012  05:30 PM    <DIR>          ..
12/16/2012  05:29 PM               960 myJar.jar
12/16/2012  05:07 PM    <DIR>          myClass'

Comment: @owlstead, Where and how do you mean to add -v?

Comment: As an option to the `jar` command, it means verbose, so it shows you what is created and added.

Comment: I think you are making a mistake: before I'm asking a question I'm reading tons of material and FAQ, and many times I've found there answers to my questions, and only when I'm almost despairing - I'm asking a new question. and I never abandon my questions!! When I'm getting the wanted answer-I'm thanking to the owner, and continuing in my programming. Anything wrong? How do you behave?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21223/discussion-between-owlstead-and-user1835297)

Comment: You are all right. I'm simply still newbie.From now I'll follow the rules. Thanks and Sorry.

Comment: @user1835297: now that you have edited your question, just look at the output carefully. It says: `inflated: myPackage/myClass.class`. So what's the problem? Your class file IS in the jar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the output you gave, there is no myClass.class file in the directory where you execute

```
jar -cf myJar.jar myClass.class
```

So obviously, the command can't add it to the jar: it doesn't exist. If you want to add the myClass directory, recursively, to the jar file, then use

```
jar -cf myJar.jar myClass
```

EDIT:

Just look at the output:

```
 inflated: myPackage/myClass.class
```

The myClass.class file is there in the jar file. There is no problem at all.

Comment: Oh, I've it in the myClass folder, and when I created the jar, I remember adding myClass\myClass.class, but just to here I didn't copy this, so it found the .class file, and it may be another problem. any other idea?

Comment: If you don't tell us exactly what you're doing, and where the files are, we can imagine dozens of potential causes for your problem. But we have a good chance of not guessing the right cause. Edit your question and tell us what you're REALLY doing.

Comment: Right. All is right. I did a mistake, and all this question was not needed at all. really, after adding the 'v' to the command, I see that everything is right. probably, the other programmer, who told me that there is a problem with the jaring made a mistake also, and I think to remove this question. What do you say?

Comment: @JBNizet Please could you please help me build a jar from this source code https://github.com/upictec/org.json.me I tried lots of things and even installed maven, but I can't get the jar